# I am trying to implement the loops in terraform

Tags: terraform, devops, terraform-provider-azure

I want my code to check for the images in the container registry in Azure before executing deployment files. Below is my code

```
resource "null_resource" "apply_k8s_manifests" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks

  provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = <<-EOT
      acr_name="${azurerm_container_registry.acr.name}"
      images=("hello-service" "world-service")

      for image in "$${images[*]}"; do
        if ! az acr repository show-tags --name "$acr_name" --repository "$image" > /dev/null; then
          echo "No images found in the repository: $acr_name/$image"
          exit 0  # Exit without error to continue with Terraform apply
        fi
      done

      # If images are found, proceed with kubectl apply
      kubectl apply -f Deployment-definitions/hello-service.yaml
      kubectl apply -f Deployment-definitions/hello-external.yaml
      kubectl apply -f Deployment-definitions/world-service.yaml
      kubectl apply -f Deployment-definitions/world-external.yaml
    EOT
     working_dir = path.module
  }
}
```

and when i do terraform plan this pops up

> null_resource.apply_k8s_manifests is tainted, so must be replaced
> -/+ resource "null_resource" "apply_k8s_manifests" {
> ~ id = "5037045116598348652" -> (known after apply)
> }
> Plan: 5 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.

Am I using the correct method?

I was trying to implement loop in terraform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to implement the loops before executing deployment files in terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully

The text `null_resource.apply_k8s_manifests is tainted, so must be replaced` means that the `null_resource` is "tainted". In Terraform, a tainted resource will be destroyed and re-created in the next apply. This can happen when a `provisioner` fails or when the resource is tainted manually.

A possible reason for this taint is that the script inside the `local-exec` provisioner returns a non-zero status, which Terraform may interpret as a failure, or that the resource was tainted manually.

1. **Terraform Looping**: Terraform does not have built-in support for conventional loops inside resources. Instead, you can achieve similar functionality with `count`, `for_each`, or `dynamic blocks`. However, for your scenario, the loop you have created in the shell script is suitable, since you are using a `local-exec` provisioner to run the script.
   .
2. **Improving the Script**: A possible reason for the taint issue is using `exit 0` to exit the script. A better way to handle the situation when images are not found is to use a different exit code. For example, you can use `exit 1` to stop the Terraform execution if essential images are missing.

My terrafrom comfiguration:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  # Configuration for Azure Provider
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "demovksb-rg"
}

data "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "demovksbcr"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "demovksb-aks"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "exampleaks"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_DS2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}


resource "null_resource" "apply_k8s_manifests" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      acr_name="${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.name}"
      images=("nginx" "mysql")
      missing_images=()

      for image in "$${images[@]}"; do
        if ! az acr repository show-tags --name "$acr_name" --repository "$image" > /dev/null; then
          echo "Image not found in the repository: $acr_name/$image"
          missing_images+=("$image")
        fi
      done

      if [ "$${#missing_images[@]}" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "The following images are missing in ACR: $${missing_images[@]}"
      else
        echo "All images are present in ACR."
      fi

      # Continue with the deployment
      kubectl apply -f /home/sample3/nginx-deployment.yaml --validate=false
      kubectl apply -f /home/sample3/mysql-deployment.yaml --validate=false
      # Add other deployment commands as needed
    EOT
    working_dir = path.module
  }
}
```

My images in repositories:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

when I ran the terraform plan I was not getting that again

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me what was your terraform version?

Comment: latest one as I dont provide any version it will pick the latest one.